# Apply a condition using any() or all() to multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe with a few columns and I want to check if atleast 3 of the columns meet a condition. I will prefer to not directly iterate over columns but if that is the only way, I will go with it.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(5, 6)), 
                  columns=list('ABCDEF'), 
                  index=['R{}'.format(i) for i in range(5)])
df.head()

Out: 
    A   B   C   D   E   F
R0  4   6   4   9   8   7
R1  0   7   5   0   6   4
R2  6   3   4   2   0   2
R3  9   4   7   2   5   7
R4  8   6   1   9   6   1
```

For one column, say column A, I can do this: `if any(df['A'] > 7)` but I want to check all the columns and return True only if at least 3 columns out of the 6 meet the condition. In the dataframe above, columns A, D, E individually meet the condition (i.e. have at least one element > 7), so the if statement will return True.

Comment: I have made some edits. Yes, want a boolean

Answer (score 2):

We can do `gt` then `sum`

```
df[df.gt(75).sum(axis=1).ge(3)]
```

Comment: I misunderstood the question. Nice one +1.

Comment: Why is there a `df[..]` outside? And even if that is removed, shouldn't this be `df.gt(75).sum(axis=1).ge(3).all()` to return a boolean?

Comment: @cs95's solution filters the rows

Comment: @MustafaAydın it is relate to you would like to filter the row, or you would like detect any condition met in one dataframe

Comment: Based on cs95's solution, this is my solution: 'if df.gt(5).any().sum() >= 3:'